# mysql: How to extract multiple tables from one and group by in each, then combine to one result?

Tags: mysql

My table looks like this:

```
+------+------+------+
| prov | amnt | type |
+------+------+------+
| on   |   10 | 1    |
| on   |   10 | 1    |
| on   |   12 | 2    |
| ab   |   10 | 1    |
| ab   |   12 | 2    |
| ab   |   12 | 2    |
| qc   |   12 | 2    |
| qc   |   13 | 3    |
| qc   |   13 | 3    |
+------+------+------+
```

I would like to return a table in which for each prov there is a summary grouped by type with the sum and count of each type like so:

```
+------+-------+------+------+
| prov | total | type | count|
+------+-------+------+------+
| on   |    20 | 1    |     2| 
| on   |    12 | 2    |     2|
| ab   |    10 | 1    |     1|
| ab   |    24 | 2    |     2|
| qc   |    12 | 2    |     1|
| qc   |    26 | 3    |     2|
+------+-------+------+------+
```

Basically if I do three queries with manual input for each province I will get the data in three different tables with three different queries.

```
SELECT prov, SUM(fine) AS total, code, COUNT(code) AS COUNT 
FROM table 
WHERE prov = 'on' 
GROUP BY code;

   +------+-------+------+------+
   | prov | total | type | count|
   +------+-------+------+------+
   | on   |    20 | 1    |     2| 
   | on   |    12 | 2    |     2|
   +------+-------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `prov` to `group by`:

```
SELECT prov, SUM(fine) AS total, code, COUNT(code) AS COUNT 
FROM table 
GROUP BY prov, code;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a sql aggregate like:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM tablename GROUP BY prov, type;
```

For more information about the group-by-functions: [see here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by prov and type. Here is what you need:

```
select    
`prov`, sum(`amnt`) as `total`, count(*) as `count`, `type`   
group by `prov`, `type`;
```

Answer (score 0):

change your query to be:

```
SELECT prov, SUM(amnt) AS total, type, COUNT(type) AS COUNT 
FROM table 
GROUP BY prov, code;
```